Highchart Column Chart
UniqueLevels = [Level 0, Level 1, Level 2]
Sample Input = [{name:"Level 0",data:[{name: "Job A",y: 0.26},{name: "Job B",y: 0.36}]},
{name:"Level 1",data:[{name: "Job C",y: 0.96},{name: "Job D",y: 0.29}]}, {name:"Level 2",data:[{name: "Job E,y: 0.96},{name: "Job F",y: 0.29}, {name: "Job G",y: 0.29}]}] From the above input need to generate column chart in highchart. I'm able to generate chart.But output differs
Expected output:In x axis level 0,level 1, level 2 need to be there. For level 0 Job A and Job B need to populate, for level 1 Job C and Job D need to populate, for level 2 Job E, Job F and Job G need to populate
Output which i'm getting : For level 0 Job A,Job C,Job E is populating, For level Job B,Job D,Job F is populating, For level 3 Jov G is populating.
In console data is coming correctly,but generating chart i'm not getting expected output.Please help me on this.
Thanks.
Expected output:In x axis level 0,level 1, level 2 need to be there. For level 0 Job A and Job B need to populate, for level 1 Job C and Job D need to populate, for level 2 Job E, Job F and Job G need to populate
Highchart.chart('container1', {
chart: {
type: 'column'
},
xAxis : {
categories : UniqueLevels
},
series: Sample Input
})enter image description here

You are passing two series: Level 1 and Level 2 and the data points provided are rendered as given, so for example "Job A" is assigned to the first category, and "Job B" is assigned to 2nd category, and they are both part of "Level 0" series. Could you elaborate a bit more about how you'd like the points to be laid out? You can also start by editing this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wtzdoy0r/

Added image for expected output.

Expected output:In x axis level 0,level 1, level 2 need to be there. For level 0 Job A and Job B need to populate, for level 1 Job C and Job D need to populate, for level 2 Job E, Job F and Job G need to populate

To achieve such output, you can enable stacking in plotOptions.column options and assign each points' x position to desired x-axis tick.
 plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  }

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fvkbpuLd/
API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.stacking
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.x
